# Matching Array<SqlParameter> to output of SqlParser.Parser?

Tags: c#, sql-server

### Background

As part of a database-facing application, we've found it necessary to construct and pass parameterized queries into an otherwise EntityFramework application, usually to bridge multiple client databases. We do this through pretty standard syntax:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<ReturnModel>(queryString, sqlParameters)
```

queryString is a string, sqlParameters is an Array of SqlParameter objects.

### Testing

As we build additional automated testing into the application I've found it helpful to use SqlParser as an "offline" tester. It won't catch everything, but I can do:

```
var parseResults = Parser.Parse(queryString);
Assert.That(parseResults.Errors, Is.Empty);
```

and make sure that we're not introducing any syntax errors into the parameterized query string.

I'd also like to be able to verify that we don't have any missing parameters in the generated parameter list; parameters expected in the query string, but not provided. Is there any way I can match sqlParameters against something in parseResults to do this, or make use of other features of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlParser` is a classic parser with a visitor interface for processing the results. The only fly in the ointment is the public documentation, which seems be out of step with the release and generally lacking any and all examples, to the point where it's almost useless. I'm going to assume the parser used here is the one you can find in the [`Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlParser` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlParser). Earlier versions were distributed as standalone installations and they don't use the same types.

To a first approximation, assuming a simple query, we can get the list of all parameters by visiting all variable declarations and references, and eliminating the references to locally declared variables -- these must be parameters.

```
class ParameterVisitor : SqlCodeObjectRecursiveVisitor {
    HashSet<string> referencedVariables = new HashSet<string>();
    public override void Visit(SqlScalarVariableRefExpression codeObject) {
        referencedVariables.Add(codeObject.VariableName);
    }

    HashSet<string> declaredVariables = new HashSet<string>();
    public override void Visit(SqlVariableDeclaration codeObject) {
        declaredVariables.Add(codeObject.Name);
    }

    public override void Visit(SqlBatch codeObject) {
        base.Visit(codeObject);
        parameters = referencedVariables.Except(declaredVariables).ToList();
    }

    List<string> parameters;
    public IEnumerable<string> Parameters => parameters;
}
```

To be used as (for example):

```
internal static class ParseResultsExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetParameters(this ParseResult p) {
        var pv = new ParameterVisitor();
        p.Script.Accept(pv);
        return pv.Parameters;
    }
}
```

```
string queryString = @"DECLARE @notAParameter INT; SELECT @c, @b, @a, @notAParameter";
var myParameterCollection = new[] {
    new SqlParameter("@a", SqlDbType.Int),
    new SqlParameter("@b", SqlDbType.Int),
    new SqlParameter("@c", SqlDbType.Int),
};

ParseResult parseResults = Parser.Parse(queryString);
Assert.That(parseResults.Errors, Is.Empty);

var expected = myParameterCollection.Select(p => p.ParameterName);
var actual = parseResults.GetParameters();
Assert.That(actual, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
```

Season to taste with more informative assertions.

Frustratingly, `SqlScalarVariableRefExpression` has a `BoundVariable` property that seems to be able to link references to their declarations. Unfortunately, using this involves using `BinderProvider`, which pulls in a complete set of metadata from an actual database (so it can bind identifiers to database objects). The documentation on this is too scant for me to decode how to appropriately use this if you just want to do some local parsing.

This code is also incomplete in that it handles only scalar variables -- adding support for table variables is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: This is too minor to put in the answer, but there's a bit of inefficiency here: `HashSet` has no implementation of `Except`, just `ExceptWith`, so we're getting the default `Enumerable.Except` implementation, which contains its own set logic. This isn't relevant in practice because you're not likely to use so many parameters that this becomes a bottleneck (and SQL Server allows "only" 2100 parameters anyway).

Comment: I appreciate the structure, and this is quite close to doing what I want! But it seems like the visit is hitting an SqlNullScalarExpression: 
"coalesce((select top 1 Id from DataTable where Id in (@ParamList0) and FkId = a.FkId order by Id), 0)" and can't find any children to go deeper into. I may have to restructure that.

Comment: codeObject.Tokens.Where(t => t.Type == Tokens.TOKEN_VARIABLE.ToString()).Select (t => t.Text) in the "parent" SqlBatch visit seems to provide a list of referenced variables without diving into the parse tree, though I realize the Tokens enum is not considered future-safe.

Comment: @Glazius: Yes, subqueries in `COALESCE` and `NULLIF` (but *not* `ISNULL`), specifically, don't seem to be further decomposed (or at least this isn't surfaced in the parse tree). This looks like a bug to me. Using some other function, e.g. `REVERSE`, produces a `SqlBuiltinScalarFunctionCallExpression` that does have children, even if you call the function with an incorrect number of parameters, or even if there actually is no such function, e.g. `UNICORN((SELECT ..))`! This suggests various workarounds; using the token list is probably as good as any.